# How to create UIView like Notification Center as iOS 7

Tags: objective-c, uiview, ios7.1, xcode5.1, ui-design

**Hello Follks,I'm developing one *Restaurant App*.I want to create a view which float from top to bottom on touch and pan gesture with bouncing,push behaviour,gravity,collision(UIKit Dynamics).Any help will be really appreciated thanks..**

I'd like to create a **View** Like **Notification Center in iOS 7**  [image: UIView]

Sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a segmented controlled table. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20574862/segmented-control-to-toggle-through-multiple-tableviews) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078200/need-approach-to-show-tables-using-segmented-control) may be of some use to you.

There is a [PullableView example on GitHub](https://github.com/crocodella/PullableView). For iOS7 like animations, check out `UIDynamicAnimator`.

You may be able to create a custom transition to a ViewController using [this](https://github.com/TeehanLax/UIViewController-Transitions-Example). Or check out [this document](http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/217xex4xi4ws3f5wrv3w2wkh/217/217.pdf?dl=1) from Apple about pulling scroll views.

Comment: Please read out my question again.I would like to make a UIView which behaves like Notification Center in iOS 7
like gravity,Push behaviour,Bouncing,Collision,Pan Gesture

Answer (score 0):

have a look on this [tutorial](http://iosdevelopertips.com/animation/spring-based-animations-using-damped-harmonics.html), hope it may help :)